# Will merging branches delete updates

Tags: git, github

I have two branches, master and staging. I have made some updates in the staging branch. Meanwhile, someone else has made other changes in the master branch. Will merging my staging to master cause all the updates in the master branch to be deleted?

Edit: I could merge my branches without any issues. I was able to see which files for conflicting and had to resolve them after which I could merge successfully.

Comment: No, it will combine the changes from the staging branch and the master branch.

Comment: The only caveat is around how you are going to resolve the conflicts if any between staging and master.

Comment: One thing that most people fail to grasp (myself included) about git is that git isn't a magic wand. If there is content that was modified by more than one actor, as in this case, git won't solve it for you. You'll have to have a human resolve the conflict, or have a human set up an automatic way to solve the conflicts. Either way, human interaction is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we merge two branches, the resultant commit consists of data of both the branches. Nothing gets deleted. However, merging two branches may lead to merge conflicts. Merge conflicts occur when we merge two branches and the same line of a file contains different data in both thee branches. You may be required to manually resolve these conflicts and then commit again.